# What verbs drive instrumental case?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

There are a few verbs that will indicate that the following word is in instrumental case. Do you know what those verbs are?

Comment: By "the following word" I think you mean the *object* of the verb, e.g. удовлетворять (to satisfy) has this feature: это число удовлетворяет  следующим условием (this number satisfies the following condition). Neither of the answers below seems to be addressing this kind of issue. I think you should rewrite your question to be clearer about what you are asking and provide the examples of such verbs that you already know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of such verbs.
Technically if you can remake sentence with using *by* + *participle* or just using *participle*, or you can say that some action was made *with*, *via* or *by way of* something as an instrument it may be instrumental case.

For instance:

`Я  написал письмо  пером.`           ['ʝа nɐpʲɪ'sɑɫ pʲɪsʲ'mo pʲɪ'rom]

`I  wrote   (the) letter    with (a) quill pen.`

`I  wrote   (the) letter    by (using) (a) quill pen.`

`Говорит она сама с собою.` [gɐvɐ'rʲit ɐ'nа sɐ'ma sɐ'boju]

`She speaks to (with) herself.`

`Они решили перейти реку бродом.` [ɐ'nʲi rʲɪ'ʂɨlʲɪ pʲɪrʲɪj'tʲi 'rʲeku 'brodɐm]

`They decided to cross the river via wade.`

Comment: Everything's fine, but I cannot agree with some transcriptions. For example  this "[бродам]" seems very strange to me. Transcription "[бро́дъм]" as [this site](http://easypronunciation.com/en/russian-phonetic-transcription-converter) shows it, seems much more reasonable to me. Also, your [гаварит] is making me crazy, while [гъвʌр'и́т] seems fine to me.

Comment: Yes, maybe your variant is more accurate. But transcription is quite strange thing. When I was in school instead of й we wrote j' in transcription. I've never seen *ʌ* and *ъ* for unstressed *а*. Then when I started to attend another school I found that they use *й* for *j* sound. Maybe non native speakers hear these sounds, but they don't make any difference in words meaning.  If you want I can change transcription according to the most popular one https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Таблица_МФА_для_русского_языка

Comment: Well, yes. I think using МФА in transcription is better. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly I agree with Stepan, but not fully.

Actually in Russian we have no instrumental case. We have "творительный падеж" or ablativ. It has function of instrumental case, examples of which you see in Stepan's answer, but it has also 12 more functions. You can find full list of them in [Russian wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6).

One of the most interesting function of Russian ablativ is pointing to time or place. Check out these examples:

```
1. Я иду дорогой
2. Под мостом
3. Тем временем
4. Утром
```

Comment: What about an example like _Он стал президентом._ ?